# How to access MACD value and signal (both 2 data) in mql4

Tags: mql4, forex, macdeployqt

I am trying to create a robot in mql4 for forex trading.So i need to access both MACD value and MACD signal value.But it looks like only providing MACD value without MACD signal value.Please help me to access those values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qRRn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It provides u with both value pls look to my code

```
double macdBaseIndicatorLine = iMACD(NULL,0,12,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_MAIN,0);
double macdSignalIndicatorLine =iMACD(NULL,0,12,26,9,PRICE_CLOSE,MODE_SIGNAL,0);
```

thats how you get the values, pls give me a like if it helps u thx